# How use the functionality of <fmt:formatNumber ...> in Servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets, jstl

On my jstl-based website, I use the following tag to display prices:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="10" minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" currencySymbol="$"/>
```

This tag works great, because it even formats the currency with local settings.

However, I now want to update this value using Ajax in combination with a Java Servlet. So what I basically need, is a way to "use" this tag in my Servlet.

I actually tried rebuilding the functionality by looking at the source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2/org/apache/taglibs/standard/tag/rt/fmt/FormatNumberTag.java

But this turns out to be quite tedious, so I was wondering if there's perhaps a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why don't you use JSP in combination with your servlet to render your AJAX response?

Comment: An example of how to do that would be great

Comment: You calculate your values inside your servlet, put them into request context and then forward to a JSP for doing the rendering stuff. For examples google for "call jsp from servlet".

Comment: This would mean I have to write a JSP-template that can parse JSON from request attributes and has some magic way of deriving from the attribute names whether to apply number-formatting to it. Not all that elegant I think.

Comment: Hm, sorry, I don't get it. Why should your JSP template parse the JSON input? First your servlet is called. It has to parse the JSON anyway. Then the servlet processes the input data producing some internal state, commonly called the model. Only the part to create the appropriate output format out of the model is different. Instead doing it inside the servlet you forward the model to a JSP to create the output. How would your servlet know when to do number formatting? You can apply the same algorithm into your JSP.

Comment: Or you let the servlet doing the decision and put a flag into your data model, so for your JSP it would be easy to decide when to do number formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Use Java's `NumberFormat` ([Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)). For formatting currencies, simply do

```
NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); // optionally provide a Locale
// optionally set currency, if different than the default for the selected locale
fmt.setCurrency(...);
String formattedNumber = fmt.format(...);
```

Comment: The problem is getting the right Locale and overwriting the Currency Symbol. I tried request.getLocale() but that doesn't work: I still get different formats.